# How to display notification using C#?

Tags: c#

I am developing an application to monitor changes to files within a folder (eg.add files, delete files, update files). I'd like to display information about detected changes in a notification similar to the one displayed by Skype.

Can anyone suggest how this could be implemented?

Comment: Do you want help with how to monitor file changes or how to display changes?

Comment: For Example, Two files exist in monitoring folder.When delete this two files or update this two files or add new files, want to display notification.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?: http://www.skylook.biz/images/Skype_28_notification.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A broad question calls for a broad answer: take a look at the [FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to detect files changing.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This site is useful for me.